# Set IAM rule in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template for deploying a service bus. The template is the one found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-overview

I am trying to add a specific user group as a Contributor and am unsure how to go about this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template) article. Basically this is the snippet you are interested in:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
  "name": "[parameters('roleNameGuid')]", << generate a guid for this value
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]", << role id
    "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]", << need to pass in group objectId
    "scope": "[variables('scope')]" << your scope
  }
}
```

contributor role definition `"Contributor": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",`